# Definition of the comparison functor in category theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, monoid, adjoint-functors, monads

I have a problem in showing that the free-forgetful adjunction $F\dashv U: \mathbf{Mon} \to \mathbf {Set}$ (call $\eta$ the unity and $\varepsilon$ the counity) is monadic, and it seems that the problem is in the definition of the  comparison functor $K$.

The adjunction above gives rise to a monad $(T:=UF, \ \eta,\ \mu :=U*\varepsilon*F)$, where $*$ is the horizontal composition. The associated adjunction $F^T\dashv U^T: \mathbf{Set}^T \to \mathbf {Set}$ consists of the forgetful functor $U^T$, whose  definiton is obvious, and the functor $F^T$ that on the objects (sets) is defined $X\mapsto (\mu _X:T^2X\to TX)$ and on the arrows acts like $T$.

The comparison functor is defined by $K=F^TU$ so, for a monoid $M$, $KM$ should be $F^TUM=\mu_{UM}:T^2UM\to TUM$, where $\mu_{UM}$ is the component in $UM$ of the $\mu$ defined above via horizontal composition. However I read that the action of $K$ should be $M\mapsto (\varepsilon_M:TM\to M)$, that actually makes clear why $K$ is essentially surjective (since $\varepsilon_M$ is the realization of the product we obtain again the initial monoid $M$). How do this two definition conciliate? Or am I misunderstanding something? (The definitions that I wrote come from my lessons). Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the wrong comparison functor. The functor $K$ must satisfy $U^TK=U$, so for a monoid $M$, the underlying set of the T-algebra $K(M)$ should be the underlying set of $M$, thus $K(M)=(U(M),h)$ for some function $h\colon TU(M)\to U(M)$ that satisfy the axioms of a $T$-algebra. In fact, in order for $K$ to also satisfy $KF=F^T$, this $h$ must be given by $U(\epsilon_M)\colon UFU(M)\to U(M)$.

Comment: I think that you mean $KF=F^T$; in that case it should be all clear.

Comment: @Dorian Yes, that's what I meant, thanks.

Comment: Actually I have one minor doubt. Your osservation defines $K$ only on the free monoids, then we can choose  to extend this definition on all monoids and verify that this is a functor for real. Is there a theorem that comparison functor is unique? Or should I use an argument of the type "if K is defined on all free monoids is defined on all monoids" (that I don't know if it's true but recalls the argument that is always made to extend homomorphisms in general). Thank you

Comment: No, $K$ is defined for all monoids.

Comment: If you use $KF=F^T$, you are defining esplicitely $K$ only on the image of $F$

Comment: $K$ is defined on all monoids, and it is indeed the unique functor such that $KF=F^T$ and $U^TK=U$. The proof that $h$ must be equal to $U(\epsilon_M)$ is not completely trivial though.

Comment: Since the comparison functor is unique, is not enogh to prove that $K(M)=(U(M),U(\epsilon _M))$ is well defined? You already  checked that $KF=F^T$ and $U^TK=U$

Comment: The functor is unique *because* the map $h$ must be equal to $U(\epsilon_M)$.

Comment: I don't understand; by definition the comparison functor $K$ is the unique functor such that $KF=F^T$ and $U^TK=U$. If I define a functor and check those two properties, why can't I conclude that it is the comparison functor?

Comment: If you want to use that as the definition, you need to prove that there exists a functor with these properties and that no other functor satisfies these properties.

Comment: I'm using the theorem IV.3.1 in Mac Lane, it says that the functor $K$ with those properties exists and is unique; is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. To prove uniqueness, Mac Lane shows that $h=U(\epsilon)$ is the only possible choice.